# how to ask someone to answer frankly?

Tags: phrase-usage

I do not know how to ask someone to be frank.
Actually I have request from someone and I want  to send an email to ask whether he would do it for me or not.

Comment: I am afraid this is "too broad". Give some context and make the question to the point, else the question might get closed very soon.

Comment: Post your best effort at formulating your request here, and then ask any questions you have about it.

Comment: Could you not say "Please be frank."? I suppose you could also say "Level with me. Will you do this or not?"

Comment: Don't sugar coat it, give me it straight, tell it like it is, tell me how you really feel, don't hold back.

Comment: @Jim - had that been an answer, I would've upvoted it. Those suggestions are excellent. It might be worth noting that those could be considered four different ways to make the request, or they could be strung together for emphasis, too. To the O.P.: a simple _"Please, be honest with me"_ can work, too.  (Also, sometimes we see [_sugarcoat_](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sugar+coat%2Csugarcoat&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) as a single word.)

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, `Level with me.` What does it mean? Come down to my level of respect, kind of that?

Comment: @Mistu4u It's a colloquialism that comes from an older colloquial expression, *on the level*, which means *fair, honest, straightforward, true*.  I think it's a spatial metaphor much like *straightforward* is.

Answer (score 2):

> Please be frank.

Sometimes, the direct approach is the best :)

Or, if you want to mealy mouthed, "I don't want you to be afraid to answer. Please tell me honestly how you feel."